# convert data-n-head="ssr" into data-vue-meta="ssr" in nuxt

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I have a website built on Vue and Nuxt. It is rendering meta tag with data-n-head="ssr" automatically. Instead of it, I want data-vue-meta="ssr". How could I achieve this? I have already tried chatGPT code and it didn't work.

Instead of < meta data-n-head="ssr" name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" >

I want this < meta data-vue-meta="ssr" name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" >

Comment: nuxt2 or nuxt3?

Comment: @DengSihan nuxt2